# Thunderbird "building summary file for inbox" error

Tags: thunderbird

Recently i have upgraded the ubuntu version 9.10 to ubuntu 10.10. After that if i open thunderbird my system gets hang and it is becoming too slow. The error i get is "Building summary file for inbox".

[image: thunderbird]

Comment: It can be a faulty drive. Look at `/var/log/syslog` for disk error messages or check the disk (see **Disk Utility**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following these steps:

1. Exit Thunderbird.
2. Make a backup of `~/.thunderbird/<something random here>.default/Mail/`
3. Remove all files with the extension "msf" in it.
4. Now try launching Thunderbird and see if the problem continues.
5. If it doesn't, restore the msfs from the backup.

Comment: @karthick87 Have you tried it yet? :)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Thunderbird create an index of all your files to provide the search function on the top right corner. So this is not an error, this is a feature. Depending on the amount of files this could take a while.

You can disable this behavior in the options under advanced, look for `Enable Global Search and Indexer.`

Comment: No i dont think that is the right option. Coz after disabling the option also the problem continues.